# Need to call Kurento Media Server opencv plugin in Android client

Tags: android, opencv, webrtc, kurento

**What i did:**

1. I have installed the opencv-plugin-sample in the Kurento Media Server.
   https://www.kurento.org/docs/6.0.0/installation_guide.html
   https://github.com/Kurento/kms-opencv-plugin-sample
2. I have modified the kms-crowd detector client-js to call opencv plugin.
3. Run the following command and load the page in browser.

   bower install

   http-server

   http://localhost:8080/index.html?ws_uri=ws://localhost:8888/kurento#

It works well.

**What i have to do:**

1. I want to replace the client-js to android mobile client.
2. I have tried to run the AppRTCDemo application. it works well.
   https://github.com/apeunit/AppRTC-Kurento-Example
3. Now I want to call KMS and apply "opencv plugin" filter from android client.
4. I don't have any references to add the "opencv plugin" call form "android" client.

How to add apply the opencv plugin filter from android client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Android mobile client. My suggestion is to follow a different application architecture, and have your Android app connecting to an application server that acts as signaling server. This server will be the one controlling KMS, and your app will only need to communicate with your application server, following this schema
[image: NodeJS or Java application server architecture with Kurento]

That will simplify your Android client development. You can check tutorials following both approaches: [NodeJS](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node) and [Java](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java)

---

EDIT 1

If you still decide that you want to directly control the media server from your Android app, you'll need to implement the [Kurento Protocol](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/stable/mastering/kurento_protocol.html): a JSON-RPC based protocol that controls the media server, through a websocket connection. The NodeJS, JS and JAVA clients are just implementations of this protocol, to ease the development process.

When you define your module in the .kmd file, you are declaring the interface for it. Whatever methods you have there, are to be invoked via the websocket control port.

I'm sure you are bound to find some Android client implementation of the Kurento Client in Github, but bear in mind that it is not officially supported.

---

EDIT 2

There's another option, which is to build your app using the [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/), which will allow you to use the Kurento Client for Javascript, and also the code generated by the module creator.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But Is it possible to call the opencv filter from android client in the current architecture without adding the above architecture? 
Because, My aim is only to detect the user's face and store it in my server(Not video/audio chat). For my requirement, I need to use only loop back(with face detection).

Comment: We have planned to use the node.js to communicate with the KMS from Android client. So we need to generate the "kurento-module-opencvpluginsample-js" for node js. We have the steps to generate the folders for JS and Java.
For Java - cmake .. -DGENERATE_JAVA_CLIENT_PROJECT=TRUE and For JS - cmake .. -DGENERATE_JS_CLIENT_PROJECT=TRUE. 
Do you have the step to generate the ""kurento-module-opencvpluginsample-js"" folder for node js? I mean, For Node JS - ???

Comment: That also creates the code for NodeJS. Just look in the Javascript folder.